# Split string by space and comma using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

String would be a list of emails; either comma separated or with spaces.

How do I split that string to get the emails (using js)?

I've tried 

`var emails = string.split('/\s+|,/');`

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the quotes :

```
var emails = string.split(/\s+|,/);
```

The `/` make a [regular expression literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression), which doesn't have to be embedded in a string literal.